# How do I format date string in order to compare two strings?

Tags: xml, xslt

What I am trying to do with my xslt code is compare two dates. However the dates are not in the same format in the 2 elements. For that reason my code is not displaying the date.

How do I modify my xslt code to achieve my goal?

**XSLT code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Charge[($pCallType='Deleted') or (Deleted!='true') or (string-length(Deleted)=0)]/
    ChargeHistory[($pCallType='Deleted') or (Deleted!='true') or (string-length(Deleted)=0) or (TimestampChange > ancestor::ControlPoint/@Timestamp)][@Stage='Warrant Issued'][last()]">
```

**The 2 xml elements with the date and time that I am comparing**

```
<ControlPoint Timestamp="9/28/2015 1:26:26 PM"></ControlPoint>

<TimestampChange>09/28/2015 13:26:30</TimestampChange>
```

Comment: Do you use XSLT 2.0 or 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
  10000000000 * substring(TimestampChange, 7, 4) 
+ 100000000 * substring(TimestampChange, 1, 2) 
+ 1000000 * substring(TimestampChange, 4, 2)
+ 10000 * substring(TimestampChange, 12, 2)
+ 100 * substring(TimestampChange, 15, 2)
+ substring(TimestampChange, 18, 2)
```

to convert the `TimestampChange` string to a number (in your example, `20150928132630`).

Use a similar logic to convert the `ControlPoint/@Timestamp` string to a comparable number (this will be more difficult, due to the lack of padding and the use of a 12-hour clock).

In XSLT 2.0, you need to convert the substrings to numbers before you can multiply them.